# How to change where Remote - SSH puts files

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have restrictions on the home directory of my remote machine, is there a way to change where Vscode Remote - SSH puts it's collateral files (~/.vscode, ~/.vscode-server, ...)?

I've looked through all the settings and haven't found anything that looks right

I need the ~/.vscode to be located somewhere besides home folder

Answer (score 2):

I found the active feature request https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/472

To get around this for now you can link `~/.vscode-server` to another folder/drive

```sh
ln -s /path/to/big/disk/.vscode-server ~/.vscode-server
```

Comment: Unfortunately that feature request is still open (as of Nov. 2020).